# How can I put the slider across the screen width and then the navigation bar appears?

Tags: navbar, gwtbootstrap3

Hello I am editing a template and it does not work quite well, since I want that when I enter the site, I see the slider and when doing scrool downwards, after the slider the navigation bar appears and stays fixed.
I wanted it to be as in this image: https://ibb.co/6FrrSQP
You see the complete image without seeing the links in the navigation bar, and then the navigation bar is up.

[image]

and then the navigation bar is up, like the image:
https://ibb.co/VLm7zcn

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,600,700,300,800);

body {
  background: #fff;
  font-family:'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  color:#333;
  line-height:1.6em;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    font-weight:500; 
    font-family:'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
 color:#333;
}

h1{
  font-size: 36px;
  color:#fff;
}

h2{
  font-size: 20px;
}

h3{
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #787878;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 24px;
}

h4{
  font-size: 16px;
}

a {
  color: #E8CE0E;
  -webkit-transition: color 300ms, background-color 300ms;
  -moz-transition: color 300ms, background-color 300ms;
  -o-transition:  color 300ms, background-color 300ms;
  transition:  color 300ms, background-color 300ms;
}

a:hover, a:focus {
  color: #d43133;
}

hr {
  border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}


.btn-primary {
  padding: 8px 20px;
  background: #E8CE0E;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border:none;
  margin-top: 10px;
}


.btn-primary:hover, 
.btn-primary:focus{
  background: #E8CE0E;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
} 

.btn-transparent {
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
}

.btn-transparent:hover {
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: -1px;
  min-width: 180px;
}

.center h2{
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.media>.pull-left{
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.media>.pull-right{
  margin-left: 20px;
}

body > section {
  padding: 70px 0;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 55px;
}

.scaleIn {
  -webkit-animation-name: scaleIn;
  animation-name: scaleIn;
}

.lead{
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.transparent-bg {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes scaleIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes scaleIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    -ms-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}


/*************************
*******Header******
**************************/
.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.navbar>.container .navbar-brand{
  margin-left: 0;
}

.top-bar {
  padding: 10px 0;
  background: #090909;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
  line-height: 28px;
}

.social{
  text-align: center;
}

.social-share{
 display: inline-block;
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

ul.social-share li {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul.social-share li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  background: #404040;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

ul.social-share li a:hover {
  background: #E8CE0E;
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar-brand {
  padding: 0;
  margin:0;
  color:#E8CE0E;
}
.navbar-header a.navbar-brand {
  color:#E8CE0E;
}

.navbar {
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background: #151515;
  padding: 15px 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

 .navbar-nav{
  margin-top: 12px;
 }

.navbar-nav>li{
  margin-left: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 28px;
}

.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-nav > li > a {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-nav > li > a:hover{
 background-color: #E8CE0E;
  color: #333;
}

.navbar-fixed-top {
  border: none;
}

.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-brand {
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus,
.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
  background-color: #E8CE0E;
  color: #333;
}

.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.85);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  border-top: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu:before{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
}

.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu > li > a {
  padding: 8px 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu > li:hover > a,
.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu > li:focus > a,
.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu > li.active > a {
  background-color: #E8CE0E;
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu > li:last-child > a {
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
}

.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu > li.divider {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-form {
  border-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}


/*************************
*******Home Page******
**************************/


.slider {
  position: relative;
  margin-top:130px;
}

#carousel-slider {
  position: relative;
}

#carousel-slider .carousel-indicators {
  bottom: -25px;
}

#carousel-slider .carousel-indicators li {
  border: 1px solid #ffbd20;
}

#carousel-slider a i {
  border: 1px solid #777;
  border-radius:50%;
  font-size: 28px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  color:#777;
}

#carousel-slider a i:hover {
  background:#E8CE0E;
  color:#fff;
  border: 1px solid #E8CE0E;
}

#carousel-slider 
.carousel-control {
  width:inherit;
}

#carousel-slider .carousel-control.left i {
  left:-25px
}

#carousel-slider .carousel-control.right i {
  right: -25px;
}

#carousel-slider
.carousel-control.left, 
#carousel-slider
.carousel-control.right {
  background: none;
}



#feature {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
#feature.transparent-bg {
  margin-top:-40px;
  
}
.features{
  padding: 0;
}

.feature-wrap {
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.feature-wrap h2{
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.feature-wrap .pull-left {
  margin-right: 25px;
}

.feature-wrap i{
  font-size: 48px;
  height: 110px;
  width: 110px;
  margin: 3px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  line-height: 110px;
  text-align:center;
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #E8CE0E;
  border: 3px solid #ffffff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px #f2f2f2;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px #f2f2f2;
  -webkit-transition: 500ms;
  -moz-transition: 500ms;
  -o-transition: 500ms;
  transition: 500ms;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 25px;
}

.feature-wrap i:hover {
  background: #E8CE0E;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px #E8CE0E;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px #E8CE0E;
  border: 3px solid #E8CE0E;
}

#recent-works .col-xs-12.col-sm-4.col-md-3{
  padding: 0;
}

.recent-work-wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.recent-work-wrap img{
  width: 100%;
}

.recent-work-wrap .recent-work-inner{
  top: 0;
  background: transparent;
  opacity: .8;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.recent-work-wrap .recent-work-inner h3{
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.recent-work-wrap .recent-work-inner h3 a{
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #fff;
}

.recent-work-wrap .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
  transition: opacity 500ms;  
  padding: 30px;
}

.recent-work-wrap .overlay .preview {
  bottom: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.recent-work-wrap:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.services-wrap .pull-left {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

#middle {
  background: #fff;
  margin-top:-90px;
}

.skill h2{
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.progress-wrap{
  position: relative;
}

.progress .color1,
.progress .color1 .bar-width{
  background: #2d7da4;
}

.progress .color2,
.progress .color2 .bar-width{
  background: #6aa42f;
}

.progress .color3,
.progress .color3 .bar-width{
  background: #ffcc33;
}

.progress .color4,
.progress .color4 .bar-width{
  background: #db3615;
}

.progress, 
.progress-bar {
  height: 15px;
  line-height: 15px;
  background: #e6e6e6;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  text-align: right;
}

.progress{
  position: relative;
}

.progress .bar-width{
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
  top: -30px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-left: -30px;
}

.progress span{
  position: relative;
}

.progress span:before{
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  border-width: 8px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  bottom: -15px;
  right: 8px;
}

.progress .color1 span:before{
  border-color: #2d7da4 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.progress .color2 span:before{
  border-color: #6aa42f transparent transparent transparent;
}

.progress .color3 span:before{
  border-color: #ffcc33 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.progress .color4 span:before{
  border-color: #db3615 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.accordion h2{
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.panel-default{
  border-color: transparent;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading,
.panel{
  background-color: #e6e6e6; 
  border:0 none;
  box-shadow:none;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading+.panel-collapse .panel-body{
  background: #fff;
  color: #858586;
}

.panel-body{
  padding: 20px 20px 10px;
}

.panel-group .panel+.panel{
  margin-top: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
}

.panel-group .panel{
  border-radius: 0;
}

.panel-heading{
  border-radius: 0;
}

.panel-title>a{
  color: #4e4e4e;
}

.accordion-inner img{
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.accordion-inner h4{
  margin-top: 0;
}

.panel-heading.active{
  background: #1f1f20;
}

.panel-heading.active .panel-title>a{
  color:#fff;
}

a.accordion-toggle  i{
  width: 45px;
  line-height: 44px;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: -15px;
  background: #c9c9c9;
}

.panel-heading.active a.accordion-toggle i{
  background: #E8CE0E;
  color: #fff;
}

.panel-heading.active a.accordion-toggle.collapsed i{
  background: #E8CE0E;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav-tabs>li{
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}

.nav-tabs{
  border-bottom: transparent;
  border-right: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}

.nav-tabs>li>a {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  color: #666;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 0 none;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin-right:0;
  padding: 13px 15px;
}

.nav-tabs li:last-child{
  border-bottom: 0 none;
} 

.nav-stacked>li+li{
  margin-top: 0;
}

.nav-tabs>li>a:hover{
  background: #1f1f20;
  color:#fff;
}

.nav-tabs>li.active>a, 
.nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover, 
.nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus {
  border: 0;
  color:#fff;
  background: #1f1f20;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-tabs>li.active>a:after {
  position: absolute;
  content:  "";
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #1f1f20;
  border-width: 25px 22px;
  right: -44px;
  top:0;
}

.tab-wrap{
  border:1px solid #e6e6e6;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.tab-content{
  padding: 20px;
}

.tab-content h2{
  margin-top: 0;
}

.tab-content img{
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.testimonial h2{
  margin-top: 0;
}

.testimonial-inner {
  color:#858586;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#partner {
  background: url(../images/partners/partner_bg.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

#partner {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

#partner h2, 
#partner h3 {
  color: #fff;
}

.partners ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.partners ul li{
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
}

.validation {
    color: red;
    display:none;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    font-weight:400;
    font-size:13px;
}

#sendmessage {
    color: green;
    border:1px solid green;
    display:none;
    text-align:center;
    padding:15px;
    font-weight:600;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}

#errormessage {
    color: red;
    display:none;
    border:1px solid red;
    text-align:center;
    padding:15px;
    font-weight:600;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}

#sendmessage.show, #errormessage.show, .show {
 display:block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Gp Bootstrap Template</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

</head>

<body class="homepage">
  

  <div class="slider">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="about-slider">
        <div id="carousel-slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <!-- Indicators -->
          <ol class="carousel-indicators visible-xs">
            <li data-target="#carousel-slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-slider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          </ol>

          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
              <img src= "https://ibb.co/n0B1kHy" class="img-responsive" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src= "https://ibb.co/F6x1BjG" class="img-responsive" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src= "https://ibb.co/F6x1BjG" class="img-responsive" alt="">
            </div>
          </div>

          <a class="left carousel-control hidden-xs" href="#carousel-slider" data-slide="prev">
      <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>
     </a>

          <a class=" right carousel-control hidden-xs" href="#carousel-slider" data-slide="next">
      <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
     </a>
        </div>
        <!--/#carousel-slider-->
      </div>
      <!--/#about-slider-->
    </div>
  </div>
  <header id="header">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="banner">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Gp.</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about-us.html">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact-us.html">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/.container-->
    </nav>
    <!--/nav-->

  </header>
  <!--/header-->
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

[image]

It starts with a slider, but the images that I put in this slider, do not occupy the total width of the screen.
The template uses Bootstrap v3.3.0. I have searched for bootstrap information, but it is not clear to me how I can do what I am looking for.
Despite being the navigation bar below the slider, it appears above when you open the site.
How can I put the slider and when I do scrool, that the navigation bar is fixed at the top of the page?
I hope to show the necessary code so they can help me.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved the goal I intended, thanks to the help of the @MariCruz user of stackoverflow in Spanish who offered a reward and another user contributed solving the problem, @JheymanMejia
Everything was corrected leaving the `navbar` fixed. Boostrap already has a class to achieve it: `navbar-fixed-top` This class is added inside the tag `nav` next to the other classes:

```
<nav class = "navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
```

In this way, what is going to happen is that the fixed menu becomes an absolutely positioned element, therefore, the carousel will be located right under the menu and at the top of the top.

the OP wishes that its menu has a transparent background, and that this one changes when the user moves down in the navigation when doing scroll.

There are many different ways to do it, but the one I propose is using jQuery, which is already necessary for Boostrap in this exercise.

I also added the transition property with a value of .5s (half a second), this determines the time it takes for the transparent color change to yellow, creating a fade-like effect that is visually appealing, but not mandatory.

The final code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop(),
      navbar = $('.navbar');

    if (scrollPos > 50) {
      navbar.addClass('alt-color');
    } else {
      navbar.removeClass('alt-color');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.navbar.alt-color {
  background-color: yellow !important;
} 


/* Ignorar: Solo a modo de prueba */
.texto-ejemplo {
  width: 10%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <!--Botstrap 3 CSS-->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  </head>


    
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
          </div>

          <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
      </nav>
    



    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

        <div class="item active">
          <img src="https://bootstrapmade.com/demo/themes/Gp/images/slider_one.jpg" alt="..." width="100%">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Slide 1</h3>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="https://bootstrapmade.com/demo/themes/Gp/images/slider_one.jpg" alt="..." width="100%">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Slide 2</h3>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="https://bootstrapmade.com/demo/themes/Gp/images/slider_one.jpg" alt="..." width="100%">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Slide 3</h3>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <!-- Left and right controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>




    <!-- Este código solo es un relleno para que el scroll vertical funcione a modo de demostración-->
    <section>
      <div class="texto-ejemplo">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse augue velit, vehicula eu pretium in, semper sit amet sem. Suspendisse tortor quam, tincidunt id nisi ut, hendrerit sodales lectus. Proin quis mauris id arcu molestie euismod.
          Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>



    <!--jQuery-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--Botstrap 3 JS-->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

This is [the link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/230977/como-puedo-poner-el-slider-en-todo-el-ancho-de-pantalla-y-luego-aparezca-la-ba?noredirect=1#comment432528_230977) to the source of the user's solution @JheymanMejia, Thanks to him and to @MariCruz